# MATLAB mapping toolbox: write multiple feature mapstruct

Tags: shapefile, matlab, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I have a few hundred road segments, described as lines, which I am trying to write to a single shape file using MATLAB's mapping toolbox. However I can only manage to get one feature per shapefile, which isn't very useful. I have developed a work around which calls GDAL from within MATLAB using system(), but the company I work for can be sensitive about us using software that they don't specifically support, so if I can find an all MATLAB option that would be ideal.

I assume that either it's not possible, or more likely that it's really simple and I'm missing something obvious. The shapewrite() function requires a 'mapstruct' structure item, but the documentation on how to write such a thing is not very clear, I've only succeded in writing single featured mapstructs. The shapewrite documentation only shows how to write a multi-feature shapefile from a mapstruct that was just read using shaperead(), but not how to write your own multi-feature mapstruct structure.

Here's what I have so far...

```
% Lines is a structure containing all of the individual features
LineIDs = fieldnames(Lines);    
First = 1;
for LineIndex = 1:numel(LineIDs)  
    LineID = LineIDs{LineIndex};
    Line = Lines.(LineID);   
    % So now Line is a structure for that individual line, it contains
    % such fields as the X and Y vertices, the BoundingBox, the Geometry 
    % type (line in this case), and other attributes. Line is my single 
    % feature 'mapstruct'. It can be written to a shapefile using shapewrite.
    LineFileName = sprintf('TempFiles\%s.shp', LineID);
    shapewrite(Line, LineFileName)
    % Now use GDAL to merge this file with all the others into one large file.
    % These next lines are the ones I would like to replace.
    if First
        First = 0;
        MergedFileName = 'MergedFile'
        MergedFileNameF = 'MergedFile.shp'
        % If the file already exists, remove it.
        if exist(MergedFileNameF, 'file') == 2
            delete(MergedFileNameF)
        end
        % Write the file to be merged to.
        [status, ~] = system(sprintf('ogr2ogr %s %s', MergedFileNameF, LineFileName));
    else
        % Merge with the file.
        [status, ~] = system(sprintf('ogr2ogr -update -append %s %s -nln %s', ...
                      MergedFileNameF, TempFile, MergedFileName));
    end
    if status == 0
        % Merge was succesful
        % Delete temp files, etc
    end
end
```

My single feature mapstruct structures look like this:

```
>> Line
ans = 

          Class: 'A Road'
             ID: 28841
       Geometry: 'Line'
           Name: 'Willowbank Road'
              X: [3.9323e+05 3.9335e+05 NaN]
              Y: [8.0548e+05 8.0547e+05 NaN]
    BoundingBox: [2x2 double]
      DftNumber: 'A93'
       FEATCODE: 25729
             CP: 80026
```

And they are stored within Lines, which looks like this...

```
>> Lines
ans =

    A: [1x1 struct]
    B: [1x1 struct]
    C: [1x1 struct]
    etc etc
```

Comment: Eddie, No doubt this comment will be removed - but many thanks for posting the update with your solution. It has helped me with a similar problem. Regards, 10B.

Answer (score 2):

Well it turns out that it is very simple, to write multiple features you give shapewrite an array of structs, rather than a single struct. It's a shame that the shapewrite documentation doesn't describe that option, but perhaps they assume that it is obvious...

Anyway, editing the code above so that it works without using GDAL:

```
% Lines is a structure containing all of the individual features
LineIDs = fieldnames(Lines);    
First = 1;
i = 1;
for LineIndex = 1:numel(LineIDs)  
    LineID = LineIDs{LineIndex};
    Line = Lines.(LineID);   
    % This time, rather than write it to an individual file, add Line
    % to an array of structs.
    if First
       % Preallocate an array of structs with the appropriate fields.
       LinesArray = repmat(Line, numel(LineIDs), 1 );
       First = 0;
    else
        LinesArray(i) = Line;
    end
    i = i + 1;
end
% And now the multiple feature shape file can be written in one line.
shapewrite(LinesArray, 'MergedFile.shp')
```